# How to read a file line by line with arbitrary long lines?

Tags: c, file

I want to read an file of arbitrary line length line by line (I need to work with each line separately in my program). However, I am unable to make it work properly. I managed to read the first line dynamically, see my code below, but I do not know how to make my program progress through the lines. Could you please help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char* readLine(char* file_name)
{
  size_t size = 5;
  char *line = malloc(size * sizeof(char));

  if (line == NULL)
    return NULL;

  FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r");

  fgets(line, size, file);

  while (line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\n')
  {
    size = size + 5;
    line = realloc (line, size * sizeof(char));

    if (line == NULL)
      return NULL;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fgets(line, size, file);
  }

  return line;
}


int main()
{
  char* string =  readLine("config_01.dot");
  printf("First line = %s\n", string);
  string =  readLine("config_01.dot");
  printf("Second line = %s\n", string);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is also some sample lore ipsum text in case you need to try something.

```
Takimata exerci invidunt stet dolores lorem augue kasd consetetur eirmod kasd sadipscing gubergren. 
Amet magna esse elitr et sed hendrerit sit dolores justo et odio duo in. 
Justo vero eos. 
Erat consequat kasd ipsum ea sanctus rebum sed sed sadipscing invidunt. 
Et ut dolore aliquyam justo stet. Sit clita sed nostrud odio eirmod. Sed accusam aliquyam amet ullamcorper sed.
Dolore labore exerci vero.
Sit clita et et invidunt nonumy takimata gubergren diam dolore et molestie accusam aliquam quis lobortis accusam sed. 
Ipsum ipsum vero sit odio volutpat.
Takimata sit vel ipsum ipsum.
```

Comment: Always check what `fgets` *returns*.

Comment: `line = realloc (line, ...` not likely to fail, but, don't. - **if** it fails, then, what do you do?

Comment: On a POSIX system you can use the `getline()` function. It handles all of this for you.

Comment: Your function always reads the first line, since it reopens the file every time. You also never close the file.

Comment: The function should take a `FILE*` as a parameter rather than opening the file itself. And there's no need to go back with `fseek()`. Just call `fgets()` with the argument pointing to the end of the previous buffer.

Comment: You always grow the allocated memory for your line by 5 characters. It would be more efficient to grow logarithmically.